# Is there an adb (Android Debugging Bridge) command to record audio that doesn't bypass the DSP like tinycap does?

Tags: android, audio, adb, record, microphone

I'd like to be able to record audio with the internal microphone using adb commands. The problem with tinycap is that I believe it bypasses the DSP (this is a BIG no-no). Playing audio is easy enough via the activity-manager utility `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:///sdcard/Music/%file% -t audio/wav`. This will play audio with a default media player.

I was hoping there would be something similar to that but for capturing audio instead and saving to a file for a specified duration. I've looked through Android documentation pertaining to adb, intents, actions, and even dug a little into their audio and media recorders. The problem I'm having is translating those interfaces into arguments to pass along to activity-manager or package-manager in the shell. I wonder if this is even possible to do or if this is a fool's errand.

I've had success opening up the native Sound Recorder app with `adb shell am start com.android.soundrecorder`, however nothing else that I add to that command actually does as expected. Activity-Manager acts on a specified INTENT. Intents consist of actions, data URI's, mime types, categories, component names, and other extraneous keys that I don't believe are relevant to my situation. I've looked through the available actions that are listed as constants [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent). But nothing gives me the impression that my intended action is feasible.

An alternative would be to work with what I have in being able to at least open up the recorder app, and then record touch events to a file and redirect that file to the proper input event, as demonstrated [here](https://gist.github.com/Ademking/e9141c8336de77c3ea1c390dc666bfaa), to handle pressing the record button. But then I'd have to find a way to automate saving the file when the "Save recording?" dialog presents itself; and that just really complicates things and reverses any efforts with the automation.

I'm in no way experienced with the Android API, aside from what I've researched in this endeavor, so I apologize if my question is trivial to some. But I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

there are but they are a holy mess to use:
tinymix, tinycap and tinyplay